# Counting instances of words from a file in Python, only works for single letters

Tags: python, string

The below code is supposed to count instances of a particular word in a text file, though it seems to only work for individual letters. Using a string of two letters or more always returns a count of 0. I have checked, and the input I have been using should definitely not return a count of 0 for the given files.

Any ideas?

```
def count_of_word(filename, word_to_count):
    """Counts instances of a particular word in a file"""
    try:
        with open(filename) as file_object:
            contents = file_object.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File " + filename + " not found")
    else:
        word_count = contents.lower().count(word_to_count)
        print("The count of the word  '" + word_to_count + "' in " + filename + " is " + str(word_count))
```

Comment: Please add inputs and outputs

Comment: When using this file http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11-0.txt encoded in Unicode as the input:

The count of the word  'a' in TextFiles/alice.txt is 8791

The count of the word  'the' in TextFiles/alice.txt is 0

Comment: How are you downloading this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change lower-case to only the file input. Try:

```
word_count = contents.lower().count(word_to_count.lower())
```

That works for me - I get 1026 for the count of `and` in the file you refer to.

EDIT:  suspected encoding issue, so suggested specifying encoding, which worked:

```
open(filename, encoding='utf_8')
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the results are still the same. Any string longer than 1 character returns 0 matches

Comment: What happens when you try `grep -c 'and' filename`?  (`-c` gives the number of lines, not the number of occurrences)

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Get-Content alice.txt | Measure-Object –Line

Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
 2481

Comment: Python Version 3

Comment: I have no idea what `Get-Content` is, but my best guess is that the file format is not UTF-8 but some other encoding.  If you can obtain the encoding then specify that in your `open`.

Comment: Thanks, adding the "encoding='utf_8'" and ensuring all the text files were encoded as UTF-8 resolved the issue

Comment: Adding to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Did not change one line in your code, and it works, I'm wondering if this has to do anything with how you are passing `'the'` or `'and'` into the function should be `count_of_word('alice.txt', 'the')`

```
def count_of_word(filename, word_to_count):
    """Counts instances of a particular word in a file"""
    try:
        with open(filename) as file_object:
            contents = file_object.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File " + filename + " not found")
    else:
        word_count = contents.lower().count(word_to_count)
        print("The count of the word  '" + word_to_count + "' in " + filename + " is " + str(word_count))

count_of_word('alice.txt', 'the')
count_of_word('alice.txt', 'a')
```

> ```
> ~/python/stack/sept/twenty_2$ python3.7 alice.py
> The count of the word  'and' in alice.txt is 2505
> The count of the word  'a' in alice.txt is 9804
> ```